# CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu Trusty VMs picking up domain name

Tags: ubuntu, dns, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using Vagrant to provision a CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu Trusty64 VM running under VirtualBox. I'm using Vagrantfiles to set the hostnames and IPs, but I notice that when I boot them, both machines are picking up a domain name which is then finding its way into SSL keys. The host machine is Windows 7 and the VMs are picking up the domain from it.  How can I prevent this, preferably using just the Vagrantfiles?

Here is `Vagrantfile`

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# See README.md for details

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "centos65-base"

  config.vm.define "server1" do |server1|

    server1.vm.hostname = "server1"

    server1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.16.0.201"

  end

end
```

Comment: you need paste the `Vagrantfile`, then we can understand what are you talking about. If can, give some error message as well.

Comment: No errors. Here is the Vagrantfile - http://pastebin.com/tN6Rq70m

Comment: Ok, I saw `Vagrantfile`, it looks fine. I added it in your question directly. My question for you is, what's the meaning of `both machines are picking up a domain name which is then finding its way into SSL keys. ` ? what's your real problem?

Comment: The problem is that instead of `server1` the FQDN becomes `server1.domain.com`. I don't know if it's picking up the domain from DHCP or from the host machine itself, which is a Windows Machine on an Active Directory domain (`domain.com`)

Comment: Do you mean your windows machine has hostname as XXX.domain.com? Then, yes, it gets from your local ENV.

Comment: Yes, so how do I prevent this?

Comment: You can set the hostname with domain name directory, for example, set to `server1.example.dev`

Answer (score 0):

So did you try what I suggested?

```
  config.vm.define :server1 do |config|

    config.vm.hostname = "server1.example.com"

    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.0.201"

  end
```

Comment: I don't want the hostname to be `server1.example.com`, I just want it to be `server1`.

Comment: Ben, I think BMW was giving you an example. According to the [vagrant documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) did you consider using the `auto_config: false` to manually configure your network interface?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Vagrantfile per host with this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "PUT YOUR BOX NAME HERE"
  # Define the vagrant machine name. Display it with: 'vagrant status'
  config.vm.define "PUT YOUR MACHINE NAME HERE"
  # Define the hostname.
  config.vm.hostname = "PUT YOUR HOSTNAME HERE"
end
```

Both, CentOS 6.6 & 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 & 14.10 are taking the right hostname. You can also add a domain with something like this:

```
hostname = 'servername'
domain   = 'example.com'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "PUT YOUR BOX NAME HERE"
  # Define the vagrant machine name. Display it with: 'vagrant status'
  config.vm.define "PUT YOUR MACHINE NAME HERE"
  # Define the hostname.
  config.vm.define hostname + '.' + domain
end
```

Again, this is one Vagrantfile per host.